# Specific list format Python

Tags: python

I have researched a lot of similar questions but I can't seem to find a solution on them or on my own. What I want to achieve is to get two dictionaries of this form each:

```
{'apple': ['5', '65'], 'blue': ['9', '10', '15', '43'],
'is': ['5', '6', '13', '45', '96'], 'yes': ['1', '2', '3', '11'], 
'zone': ['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45']}

{'apple': ['43'], 'appricote': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
'candle': ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9'], 'delta': ['14', '43', '47'], 
'dragon': ['23', '24', '25', '26'], 'eclipse': ['11', '13', '15', '19'], 
'island': ['1', '34', '35']}
```

And I want to have to following format:

```
apple ['5', '43', '65']
apricot ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
blue ['9', '10', '15', '43']
candle ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9']
delta ['14', '43', '47']
dragon ['23', '24', '25', '26']
eclipse ['11', '13', '15', '19']
is ['5', '6', '13', '45', '96']
island ['1', '34', '35']
yes ['1', '2', '3', '11']
zone ['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45']
```

But this is the format I get:

```
apple [['5', '65'], ['43']]
blue [['9', '10', '15', '43']]
is [['5', '6', '13', '45', '96']]
yes [['1', '2', '3', '11']]
zone [['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45']]
appricote [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']]
candle [['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9']]
delta [['14', '43', '47']]
dragon [['23', '24', '25', '26']]
eclipse [['11', '13', '15', '19']]
island [['1', '34', '35']]
```

This is my code so far

```
def merge_dictionaries(dict1, dict2): 
    from itertools import chain
    from collections import defaultdict

    dict3 = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
        dict3[k].append(v)

    for k, v in dict3.items():
        print(k, v)
```

So my question is should I further process the format I have now or is it possible to achieve the format I want straight away. 
For example if you tell me to process the format I already have achieved I can merge the sub-lists into one list for each key and then sort, and the sort the keys also. But I want to know if there is a more direct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way without `collections`. The idea is to iterate union of dictionary keys and then to utilise the default parameter of `dict.get`.

```
d1 = {'apple': ['5', '65'], 'blue': ['9', '10', '15', '43'],
      'is': ['5', '6', '13', '45', '96'], 'yes': ['1', '2', '3', '11'], 
      'zone': ['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45']}

d2 = {'apple': ['43'], 'appricote': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
      'candle': ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9'], 'delta': ['14', '43', '47'], 
      'dragon': ['23', '24', '25', '26'], 'eclipse': ['11', '13', '15', '19'], 
      'island': ['1', '34', '35']}

res = {}

for key in set().union(*(d1, d2)):
    res[key] = sorted(d1.get(key, []) + d2.get(key, []), key=int)
```

Result:

```
{'apple': ['5', '43', '65'],
 'appricote': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
 'blue': ['9', '10', '15', '43'],
 'candle': ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9'],
 'delta': ['14', '43', '47'],
 'dragon': ['23', '24', '25', '26'],
 'eclipse': ['11', '13', '15', '19'],
 'is': ['5', '6', '13', '45', '96'],
 'island': ['1', '34', '35'],
 'yes': ['1', '2', '3', '11'],
 'zone': ['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45']}
```

---

Or via the equivalent dictionary comprehension:

```
res = {key: sorted(d1.get(key, []) + d2.get(key, []), key=int)
            for key in set().union(*(d1, d2))}
```

---

For an ordered dictionary, use `collections.OrderedDict` afterwards.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

res = OrderedDict(sorted([(k, v) for k, v in res.items()]))
```

Comment: I am sorry but when I run your first and second answer they both sort inside each list but the don't sort the keys. Thanks a lot for your answer though even though I don't understand what you are doing. I guess I have to study a lot more...

Comment: Regarding, "sort keys" - In Python <3.7, dictionaries are not deemed to be ordered. You should not rely on *any* key ordering. If they appear in a specific order, consider it purely accidental. What you should use in this case is an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: That said, I'm still confused. The output in my answer is identical to your desired OP, right?

Comment: Yes your example output is exactly how I want it. Then I am going to check the documentation of OrderedDict and use that

Comment: Actually when I save the res dictionary (I used an orderedDict) in a json file it is sorted but when I print res it shows it is unordered... Is this behavior expected?

Comment: @Vg, I can't answer since I can't see the exact code you are using. I've updated with an example of how to use `OrderedDict`.

Comment: The reason you are getting ordered by key when you save the dict in a Json file is most likely because when you save you user sort-keys=True

Comment: @jpp Hello and sorry to bother you again but I didn't want to make a new post. What if I wanted to do the same thing with more than 2 dictionaries. Is there a fully dynamic way or should I keep reusing the 2 dictionaries merge you proposed?

Comment: `for key in set().union(*(d1, d2, d3)):
    res[key] = sorted(d1.get(key, []) + d2.get(key, []) + d3.get(key, []), key=int)`

Comment: But what if I want to add a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: @Vg, In that case, you can use Chris_Rands' solution.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot for your patience and your helpful advice

Comment: @Vg, actually have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50063580/9209546

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `list.extend` and not `list.append`:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k,v in chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
...     d[k].extend(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'apple': ['5', '65', '43'], 'blue': ['9', '10', '15', '43'], 'is': ['5', '6', '13', '45', '96'], 'yes': ['1', '2', '3', '11'], 'zone': ['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45'], 'appricote': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], 'candle': ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9'], 'delta': ['14', '43', '47'], 'dragon': ['23', '24', '25', '26'], 'eclipse': ['11', '13', '15', '19'], 'island': ['1', '34', '35']})
```

You could sort the resulting lists if their order is important.

Comment: @jpp Thanks, you mean like `{k:sorted(v, key=int) for k,v in d.items()}` I guess?

Comment: And to sort inside each list (for example in first list of elements 5,65,43) i  have to parse the dictionary again and use sort() for each list right? Thanks a lot for your quick answer... it really helped me

Comment: @Vg. Yep would require an extra pass. I offered a non-`collections` answer but it requires more `dict.get` calls when you have non-overlapping keys. I recommend you test with your data. Choose what performs and makes most sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is too complex.

```
a = {'apple': ['5', '65'], 'blue': ['9', '10', '15', '43'],
     'is': ['5', '6', '13', '45', '96'], 'yes': ['1', '2', '3', '11'],
     'zone': ['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45']}

b = {'apple': ['43'], 'appricote': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
     'candle': ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9'], 'delta': ['14', '43', '47'],
     'dragon': ['23', '24', '25', '26'], 'eclipse': ['11', '13', '15', '19'],
     'island': ['1', '34', '35']}

output = []
for key in a:
    temp = a[key]
    if key in b:
        temp.extend(b[key])
    output.append('{} {}'.format(key, sorted(temp)))

print('\n'.join(output))

# is ['13', '45', '5', '6', '96']
# blue ['10', '15', '43', '9']
# zone ['10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45', '5', '6', '9']
# apple ['43', '5', '65']
# yes ['1', '11', '2', '3']
```

**Caveats:**

- Since `a` is a dictionary the order of the elements in the outputted string is not persistent (in Python <= 3.6)
- Since your values are strings they are sorted lexicographically.

Both of these points can easily be fixed if they are relevant.

Comment: `if key in b:` is rather like using a `defaultdict` though

Comment: @Chris_Rands Indeed

Answer (score 1):

Although other answers are probably more pythonic, posting here as alsternative; another solution is to flatten your value `v` before printing `print(k, v)`

example, add the following line:

```
v = [a for b in v for a in (b if isinstance(b, list) else [b])]
```

the full code would be something like this:

```
dict1 = {'apple': ['5', '65'], 'blue': ['9', '10', '15', '43'],
         'is': ['5', '6', '13', '45', '96'], 'yes': ['1', '2', '3', '11'], 
         'zone': ['5', '6', '9', '10', '12', '14', '18', '19', '29', '45']}

dict2 = {'apple': ['43'], 'appricote': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
         'candle': ['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '9'], 'delta': ['14', '43', '47'], 
         'dragon': ['23', '24', '25', '26'], 'eclipse': ['11', '13', '15', '19'], 
         'island': ['1', '34', '35']}


def merge_dictionaries(dict1, dict2): 
    from itertools import chain
    from collections import defaultdict

    dict3 = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in chain(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
        dict3[k].append(v)

    for k, v in dict3.items():
        v = [a for b in v for a in (b if isinstance(b, list) else [b])]
        print(k, v)

merge_dictionaries(dict1, dict2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply do it with one line:

```
{k: a.get(k,[]) + b.get(k,[]) for k in a.keys() + b.keys()}
```